# AppEngine: How to transfer Blobs from one app to another

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

After the AppEngine's [Files API Service Turndown](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/files_api), now we cannot directly [create and write blob](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Writing_files_to_the_Blobstore). Now how to copy/transfer Blobs from one app to another?

Comment: You can upload your blob to another app or use GCS, upload example: https://gist.github.com/voscausa/9222732

Comment: @voscausa, please turn this comment into an answer (not a link-only one of course, rather quote the key part of your code, thanks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "write" blobs, you can use blob upload to post blobs to your receiving app. To do this you have to post a multipart encoded file using an upload_url of the receiving app.

```
def post_blob(url, blob_name, blob):

    CRLF = '\r\n'
    BOUNDERY = '--Th15-Is-ThE-BoUnDeRy--'

    payload = '--' + BOUNDERY + CRLF
    payload += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="%s"' \
          % blob_name + CRLF
    payload += 'Content-Type: %s' % mimetypes.guess_type(blob_name)[0] + CRLF
    payload += CRLF
    payload += blob + CRLF
    payload += '--%s--' % BOUNDERY + CRLF

    urlfetch.fetch(
        url=url,
        payload=payload,
        method=urlfetch.POST,
        deadline=40,
        follow_redirects=False,
        headers={'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=%s' % BOUNDERY)}
    )

url = get_receiving_app_blobstore_upload_url()  # request upload url
blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key)
blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key)  
post_blob(url, blob_info.filename, blob_reader.read())
```

In the receiving app you have to create two handlers:

1. to request the upload url using `blobstore.create_upload_url()`
2. to handle the above post